AWS RDS Snapshot backup can't restore . how to do it for Inaccessible-encryption-credentials
my db instance is in status Inaccessible-encryption-credentials , but there is snapshot available for backup , I tried backup but it is showing access denied due to IAM(I think) as I dont created any I am Role, default amazon have it for my instance. what to do.
I tried and saw to modify rds instance for IAM role enable but modify button is disabled i can't do it either.
